# PDO SQL Insert Error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I got a little Problem. I got a Server with SQL Server 2000 installed and trying to access the data with php (using PDO).

SELECT's are not the Problem...I can see anything.

But if I try a INSERT...the INSERT works with no errors but the entry don't appear.

**My Code:**

```
$dsn = 'dblib:dbname=account;host=178.33.XXX.XX:1433';
$user = 'XXX';
$password = 'XXXX';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

$try = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dbo.USER_PROFILE (user_no, user_id, user_pwd,resident_no,user_type,login_flag,login_tag,ipt_time,login_time,logout_time,user_ip_addr,server_id, geheim) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");

$try->execute(array('765867','ID78767','Password','801011000000','1','0','Y','01.01.2006 00:00:00','01.01.2006 00:00:00','01.01.2006 00:00:00',null,'000','ok'));
```

If I do a SELECT right after this INSERT...I see the new entry. But the Database dont save it o.O.

Any idea?

Comment: If you can see the result with your `SELECT` statement then it is 100% guarantee that it is in the database. Are you sure you're looking into the right table?

Comment: yes, because If I do the insert again with other values...the value I saw before is away and the new one is there...

Comment: Are you sure you need quotes for those numbers?In other words all fields are varchar?

Comment: No not all http://puu.sh/8V0XP.png

Comment: Remove them where you have int.Also check for triggers in your db.

Comment: Done and there are no triggers.. damn

Comment: What do you mean dont save it.You insert,do a select and the data is there and then...what?

Comment: Yes the data is there. But not in the Database. Only in the php view. And If I change the query (the insert) and fill some othere values it does the same thing at the next refresh (shows the values but don't saves it).

I'm confused

Comment: IF its there it is in the database.Period.Maybe show us the view code.

Comment: `if(!$try)
 {
   die("Execute query error, because: ". var_dump($dbh->errorInfo()));
 }else{
  echo "ok";
 }

$last =$dbh->query("SELECT * FROM USER_PROFILE;");
echo "<table>";
while ( $row = $last->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['user_id']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";`

Comment: Have you set autocommit off? Or are you using 'transactions'? if so then you need to use 'commit()' to save the data in the database.

Comment: autocommit is on. I don't use transactions but even with transactions it fails.

Comment: Here you can see the rows (in php view) after the Insert

http://puu.sh/8V5eB.png
and here after the next ,changed, insert
http://puu.sh/8V5hJ.png

I hope you understand what I mean :)